# how to insert the loggin details to database when loggin with facebook and google +

Tags: php, html

I'm making an plugin in CodeIgniter. It's working fine except it doesn't insert logging user details into database.

Please tell me what to do. I want to insert logging details. It's only work for auto-login.

Here is my code, short code of plugin which we can place anywhere:

```
<?php foreach($logins as $login){ ?>

<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {

      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '<?=$login['facebook_app_id']?>',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.7' // use graph api version 2.5
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp"></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<?=$login['google_client_id']?>">
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Kindly check this demo of krizna.com with demo and source code. http://www.krizna.com/demo/login-with-facebook-using-php/

Comment: You could do it with ajax and php

Comment: how can i do it with ajax and php

Comment: i tried that demo in simple php it doesnot insert details into db instead it only redirect url work